# Adding additional fields to Devise Sign Up process in Rails app with CouchDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, couchdb

Id like to capture some addition information about the user when they sign up which will be stored but not used in any sign in process. This question is very similar to an existing one ( [How do I add additional fields to the Devise 'sign up' page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241486/how-do-i-add-additional-fields-to-the-devise-sign-up-page) ) however it differs in that I am using CouchDB.

The steps to add the new fields via a migration do not apply here, Im unsure how, if at all, this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties to your user model.

```
  property :first_name, String
  property :last_name, String
```

Just add these below the devise modules.